# Installing iDempiere Dev Environment-Error Java problems and Plug-in problems when build in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, idempiere

When I build project iDempiere in eclipse got error
Java problems:

```
_interp cannot be resolved to a variable
_zclass cannot be resolved or is not a field
_zclass cannot be resolved or is not a field
Absolutechildren cannot be resolved to a type
Absolutechildren cannot be resolved to a type
...
```

Plug-in problems:

```
Host bundle 'net.sf.jasperreports.engine' cannot be resolved
Host bundle 'org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot' cannot be resolved
No available bundle exports package 'com.google.common.annotations'
No available bundle exports package 'com.google.common.base'
....
```

I try to reinstall eclipse and idempiere but still got this error.

Eclip version :

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)
Build id: 20230608-1333
```

Maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: E:\DATA\Java\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: E:\DATA\Java\jdk-11.0.4
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Which iDempiere version are you trying to use?
Which installation guide are you following?